# Implementing Reflection in C++

Tags: c++, reflection

I have been interesting implementing Reflection in C++, I have a slapped together Reflection, but I am interested in seeing how others have it done. Does anyone know any tutorials, articles or sample code on how to do this?

Comment: google does.  What have you already read?  What have you already tried?  Asking a question on SO should not be your first action when you have a question, that's what you do when you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://lcgapp.cern.ch/project/architecture/ReflectionPaper.pdf

Comment: There's Boost.Fusion...  I adjusted the code in that paper quite a bit, implementing a more type safe version.  Can't share...don't own.  Hint: you can work directly with member pointers instead of void*.

Comment: Any suggestions besides boost or qt?